# How to convert a filename with special chars to be acceptable by all OSs?

Tags: php, windows, file, filesystems, filenames

I'm creating a **cloud storage**-like system where users can create files and folders.

The problem is when the files/folders have a special char and/or reserved word in the name.

The original name of the file/folder is being saved in the database but how to overcome the creation of this file/folder in the filesystem, considering all different operating systems?

For instance a filename with `/`.

Comment: You could use regular expression on their names and remove the unwanted chars when saving the file/dir to be downloaded.

Comment: @wcomnisky I know it but problem is there are a lot of them,so I search for function which handle this

Comment: Why would this get downvoted, especially without a comment?  It's actually quite an interesting and hard-to-solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try use slugify script like this one: https://github.com/kevinlebrun/slug.php